# Auto Increment an Array value using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am trying to auto-increment an array and here below is code.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 22
    [2] => 33
)
```

I want this to be printed as

```
Array
(
    [0] => 22
    [1] => 33
)
```

The autoincrement should be done in this way. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way:

```
$incrementedArray = array_values($yourArray);
```